# Dimension of subspace of $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes n}$

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products

Consider the space $V = (\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes n}$ with $n$ even. Let $(v_+, v_-) = ((1,0), (0,1))$ be a basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$. Then the pure tensors $v_{\pm} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{\pm}$ form a basis for $V$.

**Problem:** I am trying to find the dimension (over $\mathbb{C}$) of the subspace $E_{n,0}$ which is generated by all pure tensors with the same amount of $v_+$ and $v_-$ entries.

**Guess:** My guess would be $\dim_{\mathbb{C}} E_{n,0} = {n \choose n/2}$, but I am not sure how to prove this.

Comment: You write that "pure tensors" are $v_{\pm} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{\pm}$, but the term "pure tensor" means *any* tensor of the form  $v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n$.  What is correct is that the tensors you wrote down are all pure tensors, but not conversely.  Do you know how to build a basis of a tensor product of vector spaces from bases of the original vector spaces?

Comment: Oops, I meant to say that these pure tensors form a basis for $V$.

Comment: In your problem, by "all pure tensors" it looks like you mean "all pure tensors of the form $v_{\pm} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{\pm}$," but then I don't see why you are unsure of yourself if you already know the pure tensors you described are a basis (and hence are linearly independent).